# Why do truncated disk images fail sometimes?

Tags: linux, boot, imaging

I need to do some images of small systems on larger volumes. Eg. a minimal Linux installation put onto some SSD or SD Cards. Volumes are partitionated using MBR style partition tables.
As drives are larger today, the partitions only occupy small parts of the volume.

If I have three partitions spanning about 7 GB for example, I just take an 8 GB image of the 64 GB disk.

If this image is written back to another disk later, a working system should be obtained.

But quite often it just don't boot. The errors range depending on the device from ignoring the boot volume completely (on ARM devices) to stuck before or after GRUB or on root mounting by initrd  (on x86 / x86_64 systems).

Is there any mistake in doing truncated images?

Comment: How exactly do you take an image? and write it? If by `dd` then compare [this question](http://superuser.com/q/1104716/432690).

Comment: Yes, the question may spot the same problem. However no solution there either, and even a full image was written, no truncated one.